# How can I rollback to an earlier version of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed an update to VS code ( version 1.21.1 ) and I am now getting an error when I try to debug ( "Debug adapter has terminated unexpectedly" ).  It has been a while since I've tried to debug with VS Code so I wanted to first check to see if this update was the cause.

I'm working with Flask/Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse through the [vscode updates list](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21) and then just click download on the version's page you are looking for.